# Unmarshalling Large Xml files in Java

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb

I am trying to unmarshall large xml files of size around 6Gb to java object. Below is the implementation i have used to parse the large file. It works with 20Gb heap space only. I would like to reduce the memory foot print further.

```
XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("abc.xml"));
xsr.nextTag();
long addEntity = 0;
long unmarshalEntity = 0;

JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(XYZ.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
while(xsr.nextTag() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
    long start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    XYZ sample = (XYZ) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);
}
```

It keeps throwing Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded for any lesser heap. I am having 3.3 million XYZ objects if i parse the entire file. So is there a way i can manage to hold on these objects in memory since i need to do some post processing on these objects as the post processing is dependent on multiple XYZ objects.

Comment: Well ... What do you expect when trying to unmarshal a 6GB XML file to objects? The solution is, to not read them all at once. You already created a XML stream reader. Use it.

Comment: Do you need all the objects at the same time? Otherwise you could do the post processing in chunks. Or swap them out to a binary file with normal serialization and then process that file serially one object at a time. I don't think your problem is related to XML, the code looks fine. You can verify by not holding on to the objects. If the problem is that you need 3.3M objects and can't allocate memory for them you are stuck.

Comment: How to find the size of all 3.3M objects to identify that its exceeding heap size?

Comment: You can [use JAXB with StAX](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html) to process objects in a stream-like fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you parse, all the data for XML will end up being converted to Java class hierarchy that will end up in memory.

To avoid memory issues with large files, you can:

- Directly use SAX parser which is event driven and consumes almost no memory.
- Use partial unmarshalling with JAXB

This will impose some limitations on how you can process the XML data since they will never be available all at once.
If the postprocessing happens in some reasonable sized chunks of the XML, it's not a problem since you can do that in memory.
If the postprocessing needs to happen over the whole XML, one option would be to load the data into database and do the post processing there.

Comment: Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 119576912; is the exception thrown.. So i assume it uses stax internally

Comment: JAXB (JSR-222) can use both DOM / SAX parser internally, but they're being converted into JAVA class hierarchy in the end -> end up all in memory. You will have to use the SAX parser directly to avoid the memory consumption issue.

Comment: You can easily use JAXB with StAX.

Comment: @butchyyyy *but they're being converted into JAVA class hierarchy in the end -> end up all in memory* - this is a fallacy. Yes, JAXB converts XML into objects, but *no*, they don't have to end up in memory all at once.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs a concrete example of how to do this with JAXB with StAX:

```
XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance()
XMLStreamReader reader = xif.createXMLEventReader(new StreamSource("abc.xml"))
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(XYZ.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

while (!reader.peek().isEndDocument) {
  if (reader.peek().isStartElement && 
        reader.peek().asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart().equals("xyz")) {
    XYZ sample = (XYZ) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
    //do thing with sample
  }
  reader.nextEvent()
}
reader.close()
```